# Multiple Requirejs on the same page

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

Im doing an embed code for our clients, so the clients could have multiple embed of our code (cant do it over iframe). I would want to try requirejs to do it, so my question is if i have multiple requirejs on the same page, both load different js with different paths+shims, will the oncomplete function for both of them work?

like the client would have on the main content (on their cms on specific page)

```
<script src="myexample.com/video.js?key=123"></script>
```

and on the sidebar (on their cms on all pages)

```
<script src="myexample.com/content.js?key=123"></script>
```

so my video.js would have

```
require.config({path: { video : '' }..., shim : {} ....});
require(['video','utils'], function(){ do something on video });
```

and the content.js would have

```
require.config({path: { content : '' }..., shim : {} ....});
require(['content','dom'], function(){ do something on content });
```

From what i go from here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/requirejs/MwQ-CNHxGKc it seems not possible that the 2 functions would be executed, meaning it would only process one of them.

If its not possible in requirejs can someone point me to other amd loaders where its possible. Thanks

Comment: Why would you be putting config options in two different locations?

Comment: coz our client must have 2+ embeds separately, one of the embed will be in all pages while the other will be in specific page, the config options would be dynamically created on the backend depending on what the embeds are

Answer (score 0):

You could use one loader with a minimal function that start both of your modules:

```
require(['video','content'], function(video, content){
   video.start();
   content.start();
});
```

Comment: i cant do that coz the client doesnt must have 2 embeds separately, one of the embed will be in all pages while the other will be in specific page

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how Shootitlive solved it with their widget

- One can pass arbitrary parameters to each embed
- The embed code is short
- It loads asynchronously
- One can have multiple players on one page

http://shootitlive.com/2012/07/developing-an-embeddable-javascript-widget/